# SugarCRM calculated field, accessing field in one-to-many related module

Tags: sugarcrm

SugarCRM has a great feature that allows referencing fields in related modules to auto-populate fields in the primary module. However, I haven't been able to definitively determine why I can make it work in one module, but not another. I have a suspicion, but if I'm right, I have to find another way to accomplish the same thing.

This is for SugarCRM Professional, 6.4.2, hosted on our own servers.

### What Works

Using two default modules (Contacts, Opportunities): I am able to make `Opportunities.name` a calculated field that references two fields from Contacts, using the following formula:

```
concat(related($contacts, "last_name"), ", ",related($contacts, "first_name")," - ", getDropdownValue("timeline_options", $timeline_interest_c))
```

The relationship between these two modules is "many-to-many". Opportunities is the primary module, Contacts is the secondary, and the relationship name is "opportunities_contacts". Any one Contact can be related to multiple Opportunities, and any one Opportunity can be related to multiple Contacts.

### What Doesn't Work

Using one custom module (Applications, created in and deployed from Module Builder) and one default module (Contacts): I am *not* able to make Applications.name correctly reference the *same* two fields from Contacts, using the following formula:

```
concat(related($contacts, "last_name"), ", ",related($contacts, "first_name")," - ", getDropdownValue("timeline_options", $timeline_choice))
```

The relationship between these two modules is "one-to-many". Contacts is the primary module, Applications is the secondary, and the relationship name is "contacts_applications". One Contact can have any number of Applications, but every Application can only be related to exactly one Contact.

When I try to save the formula, I get this in a popup message: "Unknown field: contacts"

### What Am I Missing?

Obviously, the thing that is different in these two scenarios is the type of relationship. What I don't understand is the technical implications of that different relationship. In other words, why does the Opportunities module know about `$contacts` when the Applications module doesn't?

Is it...

1. the nature of how "many-to-many" vs. "one-to-many" relationships are stored? or,
2. the fact that in the first instance, the calculated field resides in the "primary module" of the relationship, while in the second instance, the calculated field resides in the "secondary module" of the relationship? or,
3. something else *entirely*?

The answer to this question may suggest what I might try differently in order to accomplish what I want.

### Update... What Still Doesn't Work

Since originally submitting this question, I've tried a couple more things.

- I recreated the one-to-many relationship so that **Applications is the primary module and Contacts is the secondary module**, to no avail. The same error occurs. This tells me that #2 from above is not the problem.
- I attempted a different formula, accessing a field from Opportunities, which has a **one-to-one relationship** with Applications. The same error occurs, this time telling me "Unknown field: opportunities". This tells me that it isn't necessarily the "one-to-many" relationship that's causing problems as in #1 above, but *perhaps* the fact that it isn't a "many-to-many" relationship.

### Desired Answer Has Two Parts

I want to **understand the reason for the different behaviour**, and I also want to **know the best way** to access fields in a related module (on the "one" side of "one-to-many") in order to auto-populate a calculated field in my new module (on the "many" side of "one-to-many").

My thanks, in advance!

Comment: Thanks for the question! Could you let us know which version of SugarCRM this is for?

Comment: @jmertic Professional, v. 6.4.2 hosted on our servers. I'll add that info to the original question, too.

Comment: I suspect the link may be named not $contacts but something else, check the actual link name. You can either check it in Studio/MB or go to cache/modules/YOURMODULENAME/YOURMODULENAMEvardefs.php and examining the fields listed there.

Comment: @StasM That was exactly the problem! I found the real field name by looking at the cached vardefs file. Can you turn your comment into an answer so that I can accept it, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `$contact` is not the actual name of the link, but the link may be named something else. You can find the name of the link in Studio/MB or by looking directly into the metadata file, which is stored at `cache/modules/YOURMODULENAME/YOURMODULENAMEvardefs.php`. The metadata file is the authoritative source - it is how SugarCRM views the fields of the object, including the links, so that link should be there too, and the name specified there should work.